# When build A.framework with B.framework as dependency, B.framework is embed in A or not?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

I wanna build A.framework with B.framework as dependency, B.framework is embed in A or not? Which means whether do I need to link B.framework while using A.framework.

How is framework is dynamic and static?

And how is .a?

And how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's if I can answer to the best of my knowledge.

Dynamic vs Static framework.

| parameters | Dynamic | Static |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Size of the app | small | big |
| loading the framework | when needed | during launch |
| applaunch time | fast | slow |
| resource files | can include | cannot include |

Now to the question how to set the framework dynamic or static?

In BuildSettings->Search for mach-O as shown in the pic in the link.
[Buildsettings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOUbH.png)

Now to include the framework B in A.
Go to build phases, add B.framework as dependent as linked library.
[BuildPhases Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhjV3.png)

Regarding .a this is static library.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thx, but I wanna know is that when A.framework is built with B as a dependency, whether B is embedded in A's binary or not.